# Return response body from HttpClient request

Tags: dart, flutter

Here is my code:

```
  Future<String> fetch(url) async {
    Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    String tempPath = tempDir.path;
    var cj = new PersistCookieJar(tempPath);

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    var request = await client.getUrl(Uri.parse(url));
    request.cookies.addAll(cj.loadForRequest(Uri.parse(url)));
    var response = await request.close();
    cj.saveFromResponse(Uri.parse(url), response.cookies);
        // I tried using .toString() but it returns an " Instance of '_HttpClientResponse' "
    return response.toString();
  }
```

I tried for hours to find a way to return the response body, but without any success, could someone please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, I fixed it.

I used this code:

```
  Future<String> fetch(url) async {
    Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    String tempPath = tempDir.path;
    var cj = new PersistCookieJar(tempPath);

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    var request = await client.getUrl(Uri.parse(url));
    request.cookies.addAll(cj.loadForRequest(Uri.parse(url)));
    var response = await request.close();
    cj.saveFromResponse(Uri.parse(url), response.cookies);
    // I had to transform the response for it to work
    var body = await response.transform(Utf8Decoder(allowMalformed: true)).join();
    return body;
  }
```